# MySQL Error "Operand should contain 1 column"

Tags: mysql, operand, mysql-error-1241

I could find a lot of similar questions but no real solution for my problem.

My SQL query:

```
UPDATE ADRESSEN
SET EMAIL = 0
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS COUNTER
FROM EIGENSCHAFTEN WHERE Kategorie = "BOUNCE" 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNTER = 1)
```

The error code I receive is

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

If I just use the query in the parentheses it works and the result is

```
ID | COUNTER
0002159 | 1
```

Where is my error? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Ur Sub-query is returning two columns and its no way valid...

Answer (score 12):

The issue is your inner query is returning two columns. Modify your query like

```
UPDATE ADRESSEN
SET EMAIL = 0
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
FROM EIGENSCHAFTEN WHERE Kategorie = "BOUNCE" 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1)
```

This should work.

I have one more suggestion, are you sure that your inner query will always return one row?
If you want EMAIL to be set with value 0 for multiple IDs returned by inner query I would recommend you use "IN" instead of "=".

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery contains two columns. Try this:

```
UPDATE ADRESSEN
SET EMAIL = 0
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
FROM EIGENSCHAFTEN WHERE Kategorie = "BOUNCE" 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1)
```

I removed `COUNT(ID)` so you only select the ID, and put that instead in your `HAVING` clause.

Also, unless you are sure this query will never return more than one row, you need to deal with the possibility of duplicates. Either change to `WHERE ID IN` instead of `WHERE ID =`, or limit the number of results returned by the query. The method to limit the results will depend on your requirements - adding `LIMIT 1` to the subquery will work, but you might want to do some sorting or use `MIN`/`MAX` to specify which row you get.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your subquery:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS COUNTER FROM EIGENSCHAFTEN WHERE Kategorie = "BOUNCE" GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNTER = 1
```

you're trying to compare it to `ID` but are returning two columns

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
                FROM EIGENSCHAFTEN 
                WHERE Kategorie = "BOUNCE" 
                GROUP BY ID
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ADRESSEN
SET EMAIL = 0
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
FROM EIGENSCHAFTEN WHERE Kategorie = "BOUNCE" 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```