# MySQL conditional table update Unknown Column error 1054

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- `Table_A` = stores results
- `Table_B` = to use for aggregate function

`Table_A` and `Table_B` share two columns called `ID` and `CYCLE` but `Table_B` contains multiple occurrences of `CYCLE`. I want to count the number of occurrences of `CYCLE` in `Table_B` and store them in `Table_A`. For example, if for `CYCLE` = 42 we have 20 rows that have the same value, I want to count that (i.e. 20) and store it in `Table_A` under the `CYCLE` since `CYCLE` will have the same value (42) but the `COUNT` column in `Table_A` for that `CYCLE` will contain 20. Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE database.Table_A
SET count =
(
SELECT ID, CYCLE,
COUNT(*) FROM database.Table_2
GROUP BY ID, CYCLE
)
WHERE database.Table_1.ID = database.Table_2.ID AND
      database.Table_1.CYCLE = database.Table_2.CYCLE
```

I keep getting `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Any suggestions for my query?

**EDIT 1**

The `SELECT` statement returns two columns. That's what's causing `Error Code: 1241` but now that that's solved, I get `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'database.Table_2.CYCLE' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error "Operand should contain 1 column"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707664/mysql-error-operand-should-contain-1-column)

Comment: @Drew thanks for pointing that out. I understand where the problem was with the `SELECT` statement and have edited my question to reflect that. Now I am faced with `Unknown column...` - error 1054.

Comment: You can't do update one table using data from another table, you need to use JOIN for the same. what is `database.Table_2.CYCLE = database.Table_2.CYCLE` ? did you mean `database.Table_1.CYCLE = database.Table_2.CYCLE` ? I am assuming you meant the issue for mysql

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes, I updated that as well. Are you suggesting using `INNER JOIN` after the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: Ok no more question changes ! I changed the title

Comment: I don't think Abhik meant to say his first part of sentence 1

Comment: Not sure from where Table_1 and Table_2 come, however assuming the table names as shown in the first part of the question i.e. `Table_A` and `Table_B` this query should work `update Table_A a
join ( 
 SELECT ID, CYCLE,
 COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Table_B
 GROUP BY ID, CYCLE
)b on b.ID = a.ID and b.CYCLE = a.CYCLE
set a.`count` = b.cnt;`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty You can add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You have an answer from @Drew and with some nice example you should accept his answer.

Comment: He can even do a self-answer and accept his for his exact use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old cut and paste I have for an update with a join and an aggregate:

update based on aggregate against another table

```
create table tA
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theDate datetime not null,
    -- other stuff
    key(theDate) -- make it snappy fast
);

create table tB
(   myId int primary key,   -- but definition PK is not null
    someCol int not null
);

-- truncate table tA;
-- truncate table tB;

insert tA(theDate) values
('2015-09-19'),
('2015-09-19 00:24:21'),
('2015-09-19 07:24:21'),
('2015-09-20 00:00:00');

insert tB(myId,someCol) values (15,-1); --    (-1) just for the heck of it
insert tB(myId,someCol) values (16,-1); --    (-1) just for the heck of it

update tB
set someCol=(select count(*) from tA where theDate between '2015-09-19 00:00:00' and '2015-09-19 00:59:59')
where tB.myId=15;

select * from tB;
+------+---------+
| myId | someCol |
+------+---------+
|   15 |       2 |
|   16 |      -1 |
+------+---------+
```

only myId=15 is touched.

I will happily delete it if it bothers my peers. In fact I cannot delete it today as I used up all my votes.

Comment: Please add the query related to the question in your answer so that he can accept it :)

Comment: Ok will do in a few minutes. If I get some clarity on his schema.